# jQuery resizable() and multiple alsoResizes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a way to set multiple alsoResizes in jQuery UI?

```
$('.selector').resizable({ alsoResize: '.other' });
```

I would like to set a couple of other elements to also resize, not just one. The official documentation tells nothing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try

`$('.selector').resizable({ alsoResize: '.other,.another,.andmanymore' });`

Comment: it doesn't work if you give it a jQuery collection: `alsoResize: $('.other,.another,.andmanymore')` which is unfortunate if you have a Backbone-like view and don't want to resize everything on the page (for example, I want to use `this.$('.other,.another,.andmanymore')`)  The jQuery UI code appears to avoid it entirely

Comment: thats because `this` is not a jQuery element you can do `$('.other,.another,.andmanymore').add(this)` instead or the other way round or perhasp `$(this).find('.other,.another,.andmanymore')`

Comment: @CalebHearon and also not to forget containement: http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-containment

Comment: I want resize parent element, can I use something like `alsoResize: this.parentNode`?

Comment: probably not, not because jQuery, but because in JS you this in an object `{...}`, is not a HTML element, maybe try this, $('.selector').each(function (i,n){ $(n).resizable({ alsoResize:$(n).parent() }); })` this may work, if not you can use $(n).parent().selector or something similar.

Comment: @Val in that example, `this` is an instantiated Backbone object, not a DOM element in a callback.  `alsoResize` doesn't work correctly with a jQuery collection in any case.  It will only resize the first item.  Check out the source, it explicitly uses `$el[0]`

Comment: @CalebHearon Well, worse comes to worse there is a resize handler, so you can use that, to do anything, `alsoResize` it is like a quick shorthand, it's idea was that when you have modals, or containers and you wanted to also resize the container and keep the ration the same, so have a look at http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-resize otherwise I don't know how else I can help :), most likely it's because they are `ids` as oppose to classes or I don't have much knowledge on `backbone`

Answer (score 1):

this can be done by combining the div s.

```
var foo = $('.foo').attr('id');
var bar = $('.bar').attr('id');
var bar = $('.bar').attr('id');
var alsos = '#' + foo + ', #' + bar; 


$('.selector').resizable({
alsoresize:alsos, 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have object reference then you can use like this:

```
$(el).resizable(
        {
            alsoResize: [ el.children[0], el.children[1] ]
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in an array of strings like so:

```
$('.selector').resizable({ alsoResize: [
    '.other',
    '.and-another',
    '#and-one-more'
]});
```

These strings should represent selectors.  You can also resize by class or id.